# Uploaded Files in FTP using C# gets saved as STOR

Tags: c#, ftp

I am new to C#, hence bear with me. I am trying to build a simple application to upload a file to ftp. The application works, the file gets uploaded but the filename gets changed to STOR. This is the method that I am using:

```
   private void ConnectAndUpload()
    {
        username ="username";
        password ="password";
        URLPath ="ftp://123.456.789.123";
        FilePath = "E:\\Temp\\myfile.jpg";

        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        Client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
        Client.BaseAddress = URLPath;

        Client.UploadFile(WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, FilePath);


    }
```

The filename in the ftp site has a name STOR. How can I make sure the file gets saved as myfile.jpg instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UploadFile method has overloads with 3 and 2 parameters. First parameter is always address. Method goes as a second parameter. So you need to change your code to:

```
Client.UploadFile("myfile.jpg", WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile, FilePath);
```

STOR is a value of `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile`, which gets interpreted as name of file you want to put on ftp.

Comment: What if I am dynamically specifying the value in the FilePath? I don't want to hard code it into Client.UplaodFile.

Comment: I got it. Used: Path.GetFileName(FilePath);